# Number modifying during conversion from NSString to NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

```
 NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:txt2.text];
    ctbook.number=myNumber;
```

In the above code parameter of ctbook.number is NSNumber so I convert the text field value into NSNumber before passing to ctbook.number. But when I retrieve the value from ctbook.number I got a new different number which wasn't the one I passed through the text field. What I'm missing? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: what's in the text field?

Comment: I typed some numbers only

Comment: can you provide a precise example? What do you type and what do you get?

Comment: Now I found that when the digits is more than 10 the number is modifying else its retrieving correctly @GabrielePetronella

Comment: Were you unable to use the `intValue` method of `NSString` (`@[txt2.text intValue])`)?

Comment: @Dolours you really need to give us more information, otherwise is impossible to help you

Comment: I used core data and int32 datatype for number field. Now passing ctbook.number as object to db .The value get saved differantly in db table @GabrielePetronella

Comment: @GabrielePetronella if I give Input 111111111111 the value that saved in db table is -1773790777. Aslo your answer below doesn't seem working

Comment: that's clearly an integer overflow. `111111111111` is larger than the maximum integer representable with 32 bits, therefore it will overflow going negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "Integer 32" as data type for your Core Data attribute then Core Data will (silently) truncate the value to 32 bit. If you assign a `NSNumber` value that is larger than 
`2^31 - 1 = 2147483647`, then it will be truncated to 32-bit, which explains why you get a different value when you read the data back.

You can choose "Integer 64" as data type in the Core Data entity, that would allow a maximum value of `2^63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807`.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information is hard to tell what's going wrong, but if you need something quick and dirty you can use the `intValue` or `integerValue` methods of `NSString`.

```
ctbook.number = @(txt2.txt.intValue);
```

(the `@(x)` syntax is just a shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:txt2.txt.intValue]`)

Please note that in case your string is not a valid `int`, the `intValue` call will return `0`.

**EDIT**

given the recent comments the problem is not with the conversion, but with the integer representation.

32 bits are not enough to represent your number, so you'd better use smaller numbers or switch to a 64 bit representation using `int64_t`.